# how to iterate through xml data?

Tags: php, xml

I have connected an api and gotten a response in xml format which I have converted into array but now I am stuck at how to iterate through this array. For example I want to get all the comments from this array.
Here is my array

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => array
        )

    [survey] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [censored] => false
                    [comments] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [nil] => true
                                )

                        )

                    [completed-at] => 2017-12-29T08:47:08-05:00
                    [flagged-for-follow-up] => false
                    [has-notes] => false
                    [invited-at] => 2017-12-28T18:52:40-05:00
                    [net-promoter-label] => promoter
                    [public-response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [nil] => true
                                )

                        )

                    [recommendation-likelihood] => 10
                    [updated-at] => 2017-12-29T08:47:08-05:00
                    [customer-reference] => 553
                    [customer-full-name] => Bill Hoeninger
                    [public-reviewer-name] => B.H.
                    [notes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => array
                                )

                        )

                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [censored] => false
                    [comments] => Friendly, attention to scheduling,, effective coaching
                    [completed-at] => 2017-12-29T05:26:03-05:00
                    [flagged-for-follow-up] => false
                    [has-notes] => false
                    [invited-at] => 2017-12-28T18:56:18-05:00
                    [net-promoter-label] => promoter
                    [public-response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [nil] => true
                                )

                        )

                    [recommendation-likelihood] => 10
                    [updated-at] => 2017-12-29T05:26:29-05:00
                    [job-reference] => 19855
                    [customer-full-name] => Javaid Yousuf
                    [public-reviewer-name] => J.Y.
                    [notes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => array
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [censored] => false
                    [comments] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [nil] => true
                                )

                        )

                    [completed-at] => 2017-12-29T00:39:06-05:00
                    [flagged-for-follow-up] => false
                    [has-notes] => false
                    [invited-at] => 2017-12-28T18:54:58-05:00
                    [net-promoter-label] => promoter
                    [public-response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [nil] => true
                                )

                        )

                    [recommendation-likelihood] => 10
                    [updated-at] => 2017-12-29T00:39:06-05:00
                    [job-reference] => 21505
                    [customer-full-name] => Julia Taylor
                    [public-reviewer-name] => J.T.
                    [notes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => array
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Help me out please I am stuck at this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would need to loop the XML object results, eg:

```
$comments = array();
foreach ($object->survey as $index => $survey) {
    if (is_string($survey->comments)) {$comments[$index] = $survey->comments;}
}
print_r($comments); // to see comments
```